# why does my pygame war code show up with an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

```
import random
from time import sleep
import pygame
player1=[]
player2=[]
x=0
wind=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500))
floor=pygame.Surface((1000,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("War")
back=pygame.image.load('back.png')
acec=pygame.image.load('14c.png')
qc=pygame.image.load('2c.png')
wc=pygame.image.load('3c.png')
ec=pygame.image.load('4c.png')
rc=pygame.image.load('5c.png')
tc=pygame.image.load('6c.png')
yc=pygame.image.load('7c.png')
uc=pygame.image.load('8c.png')
ic=pygame.image.load('9c.png')
oc=pygame.image.load('10c.png')
jackc=pygame.image.load('11c.png')
queenc=pygame.image.load('12c.png')
kingc=pygame.image.load('13c.png')
aced=pygame.image.load('14d.png')
qd=pygame.image.load('2d.png')
wd=pygame.image.load('3d.png')
ed=pygame.image.load('4d.png')
rd=pygame.image.load('5d.png')
td=pygame.image.load('6d.png')
yd=pygame.image.load('7d.png')
ud=pygame.image.load('8d.png')
pd=pygame.image.load('9d.png')
od=pygame.image.load('10d.png')
jackd=pygame.image.load('11d.png')
queend=pygame.image.load('12d.png')
kingd=pygame.image.load('13d.png')
aceh=pygame.image.load('14h.png')
qh=pygame.image.load('2h.png')
wh=pygame.image.load('3h.png')
eh=pygame.image.load('4h.png')
rh=pygame.image.load('5h.png')
th=pygame.image.load('6h.png')
yh=pygame.image.load('7h.png')
uh=pygame.image.load('8h.png')
ih=pygame.image.load('9h.png')
oh=pygame.image.load('10h.png')
jackh=pygame.image.load('11h.png')
queenh=pygame.image.load('12h.png')
kingh=pygame.image.load('13h.png')
aces=pygame.image.load('14s.png')
qs=pygame.image.load('2s.png')
ws=pygame.image.load('3s.png')
es=pygame.image.load('4s.png')
rs=pygame.image.load('5s.png')
ts=pygame.image.load('6s.png')
ys=pygame.image.load('7s.png')
us=pygame.image.load('8s.png')
ps=pygame.image.load('9s.png')
os=pygame.image.load('10s.png')
jacks=pygame.image.load('11s.png')
queens=pygame.image.load('12s.png')
kings=pygame.image.load('13s.png')
acesc=[14,acec,"c"]
twoc=[2,qc,"c"]
threec=[3,wc,"c"]
fourc=[4,ec,"c"]
fivec=[5,rc,"c"]
sixc=[6,tc,"c"]
sevenc=[7,yc,"c"]
eightc=[8,uc,"c"]
ninec=[9,ic,"c"]
tenc=[10,oc,"c"]
jacksc=[11,jackc,"c"]
queensc=[12,queenc,"c"]
kingsc=[13,kingc,"c"]
acesd=[14,aced,"d"]
twod=[2,qd,"d"]
threed=[3,wd,"d"]
fourd=[4,ed,"d"]
fived=[5,rd,"d"]
sixd=[6,td,"d"]
sevend=[7,yd,"d"]
eightd=[8,ud,"d"]
nined=[9,pd,"d"]
tend=[10,od,"d"]
jacksd=[11,jackd,"d"]
queensd=[12,queend,"d"]
kingsd=[13,kingd,"d"]
acesh=[14,aceh,"h"]
twoh=[2,qh,"h"]
threeh=[3,wh,"h"]
fourh=[4,eh,"h"]
fiveh=[5,rh,"h"]
sixh=[6,th,"h"]
sevenh=[7,yh,"h"]
eighth=[8,uh,"h"]
nineh=[9,ih,"h"]
tenh=[10,oh,"h"]
jacksh=[11,jackc,"h"]
queensh=[12,queenc,"h"]
kingsh=[13,kingc,"h"]
acess=[14,aces,"s"]
twos=[2,qs,"s"]
threes=[3,ws,"s"]
fours=[4,es,"s"]
fives=[5,rs,"s"]
sixs=[6,ts,"s"]
sevens=[7,ys,"s"]
eights=[8,us,"s"]
nines=[9,ps,"s"]
tens=[10,os,"s"]
jackss=[11,jacks,"s"]
queenss=[12,queens,"s"]
kingss=[13,kings,"s"]
y=0
deck=[acesc,acess,acesh,acesd,twod,twos,twoh,twoc,threed,threes,threeh,threec,fours,fourd,fourh,fourc,fives,fived,fiveh,fivec,sixs,sixd,sixh,sixc,sevens,sevend,sevenh,sevenc,eights,eightd,eighth,eightc,nines,nined,nineh,ninec,tens,tend,tenh,tenc,jacks,jackd,jackh,jackc,queens,queend,queenh,queenc,kings,kingd,kingh,kingc]
win=False
#shuffle
while y<4:
    y+=1
    random.shuffle(deck)
#deal
pygame.init()
while x<52:
    player1.append(deck[x])
    x+=1
    player2.append(deck[x])
    x+=1
while win==False:
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    wind.fill((35,110,43))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            win=True
#draw next card
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
#comparison of card values and changing of hands
#show cards
        wind.blit(player1[0][1],(426,260))
        wind.blit(player2[0][1],(426,25))
        if player1[0][0]>player2[0][0]:
            player1.append(player1[0])
            player1.append(player2[0])
            player1.pop(0)
            player2.pop(0)
        elif player2[0][0]>player1[0][0]:
            player2.append(player1[0])
            player2.append(player2[0])
            player1.pop(0)
            player2.pop(0)
#war
        elif player1[0][0]==player2[0][0]:
            print("second card player 1",player1[4][1])
            print("second card player 2",player2[4][1])
            sleep(1)
            print("cards gained",player1[1][1],player1[2][1],player1[3][1],player2[1][1],player2[2][1],player2[3][1])
            if player1[4][0]>player2[4][0]:
                for pop in range(0,5):
                    player1.append(player1[pop])
                    player1.append(player2[pop])
                for pop in range(0,5):
                    player1.pop(0)
                    player2.pop(0)
            elif player2[4][0]>player1[4][0]:
                for pop in range(0,5):
                    player2.append(player1[pop])
                    player2.append(player2[pop])
                for pop in range(0,5):

                    player1.pop(0)
                    player2.pop(0)
            else:
                print("draw")
            sleep(3)
    #win function
    handcount1=len(player1)
    handcount2=len(player2)
    if handcount1==52:
        win=True
        print("player 1 wins")
    else:
        wind.blit(back,(25,25))
    if handcount2==52:
        win=True
        print("player 2 wins")
    else:
        wind.blit(back,(828,260))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

The code works perfectly until I press the space bar for the first hand then it shows me this traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PABei\Downloads\war\war.py", line 139, in <module>
    wind.blit(player1[0][1],(426,260))
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not subscriptable
```

And I don't understand why. The code in these lines is supposed to put a card image n the center of the window. Sometimes the error shows different lines but they're all lines where I try to blit the card images. Strangely the backs of the cards work just fine, the only problem is on the face up cards. I've tried to add a second surface to blit the images onto but it shows up with the same error message. I just don't know what to do and would appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: `player1` is a list  of surface objects. It is not a list of lists. `player1` is subscriptable, but `player1[0]` is it not. What do you expect by  `player1[0][1]`? `wind.blit(player1[0],(426,260))` would work.

Comment: check again, the deck is a list of lists containing a number, a file variable and a string for the card name, the 52 items in the list are split between the two players. player1[0][1] refers to the file variable and should blit the image onto the center of the virtual table

Comment: however, the card files are in a list and that might be what makes them subscripted, but I also don't know how subscription works in python, that could be the problem

Comment: I see. But some element in the list is not a list, but a single Surface. This is caused, because not all elements in `deck` are lists. e.g. `kings=pygame.image.load('13s.png')` is a Surface object. - `kings = [pygame.image.load('13s.png')]` would be a list with one element.

Comment: the kings variable is a variable for the king of spades card image file, the kingss list has an extra s so it qualifies as a different variable and the only difference between that and kingd is that one has a king of spades and the other has a king of diamonds, however you may be correct, it may work if I use less variable and just replace the image file variables with the image load functions in the actual card list

Answer (score 0):

Some element in the list are not a list, but a single *Surface*. This is caused, because not all elements in deck are lists. `kings` is a *Surface*:

> ```py
> kings=pygame.image.load('13s.png')
> ```

Make `kings` a list with one item:

```py
kings = [pygame.image.load('13s.png')]
```